# Better method to schedule instance stop and start in Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-compute-engine

Currently I schedule my instance shutdown in **[Google Cloud Platform (GCP)](https://cloud.google.com/)** the following way via `/etc/crontab`:

```
30 23 * * * sudo poweroff
```

This is done inside GCP instance.

Is there better way to do it using GCP-API? And how can I schedule the instance starting? I can't seem to do that even with crontab.

Comment: I closed this question because it doesn't look to be a good fit for this site. It might a better fit for [webmasters.se], [sf] among other [se] sites.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great tutorial in the Google Cloud Site. The address is

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/start-and-stop-compute-engine-instances-on-a-schedule

Extra note to help with the tutorial:

When you get to the part where you are setting up the Functions.  You may need to do base64 conversion if you are using the free tier option, the tutorial is for the west zone and free tier is only available in the central zone. Also once you have the string converted you need to remove the OK from the end and add `o=`

There are my notes of the process:

sample string:

```
{"zone":"us-west1-b", "label":"env=dev"}
```

sample as base 64

```
{"data":"eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtd2VzdDEtYiIsICJsYWJlbCI6ImVudj1kZXYifQo="}
```

converter url:
https://www.base64encode.net/

results using sample string above

```
eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtd2VzdDEtYiIsICJsYWJlbCI6ImVudj1kZXYifQ0K
or
eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtd2VzdDEtYiIsICJsYWJlbCI6ImVudj1kZXYifQ==
```

The results are the same as the sample except the different in the last to characters.

desired input string:

```
{"zone":"us-central1-a", "label":"env=dev"}
```

output base 64 string

```
eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtY2VudHJhbDEtYSIsICJsYWJlbCI6ImVudj1kZXYifQ0K
```

Add the JSON formatting and adjust the last to characters:

```
{"data":"eyJ6b25lIjoidXMtY2VudHJhbDEtYSIsICJsYWJlbCI6ImVudj1kZXYifQo="}
```

Hope it helps you get the base64 string conversion bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can start and stop instances via the command line with the Google Cloud Platform gcloud command line utility:

```
gcloud compute instances start *INSTANCE_NAMES*
gcloud compute instances stop *INSTANCE_NAMES*
```

See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/start and the adjacent command for stop.  You could combine this with scripting on some other system to do the scheduling, or with Google Compute Engine and the GCP Cron Services as described at https://cloud.google.com/solutions/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine

Full disclosure: If you do not want to code this yourself, I work for a company that provides this as a service for free ([www.parkmycloud.com](https://www.parkmycloud.com)) for GCP, Azure, and AWS.

Comment: Thanks for feedback - I am a new poster and this was valuable. Updated answer with more detail, and added full disclosure and tried to make less-salesy.